# SQL Select Query giving MISSING EXPRESSION

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, reserved-words

I am running  a query on ORACLE DB 11g and am having an issue:

```
select ORDER as "_id", * from orderlines;
```

I have this error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 41
```

I tried it with and without the ; and still gives the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code is on Line:  7 Col:  41?

Comment: try this :`select o.ORDER as "_id", o.* from orderlines o;`

Comment: Order its a reserved word in Oracle you probably want double quotes

Answer (score 4):

As `ORDER` is a reserved word in many RDBMSs including Oracle, you should escape it with `"` :

```
SELECT t."ORDER" AS "_id"
     , t.* 
FROM "orderlines" t
```